# Как создать иконку для скрипта в Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, установка

Как создать иконку на рабочем столе, чтобы не прописывать в терминале `./fail.sh`?

Comment: можно по простому сделать `ln -s` на `~/Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Создай значок запуска и все, можно в usr/share/application